# How can I change the icon size in Lauchpad?

Tags: macos, launchpad

The icon in Launchpad look huge on my iMac and I usually like my icons fairly small.

Is there a setting to resize the icon app size in Lauchpad?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in terminal:

Launch Terminal and type the below 3 lines, you can make the icon smaller by increasing the number of rows and columns (I use 7x7) (10x10 will be too small):

```
defaults write com.apple.dock springboard-columns -int 7
defaults write com.apple.dock springboard-rows -int 7
killall Dock
```

To reset to the default sizes:

```
defaults delete com.apple.dock springboard-columns
defaults delete com.apple.dock springboard-rows
killall Dock
```

Comment: You can also choose to set just one parameter and the system will compute the other.  For my system, I configure 10 columns, and macOS computes some number of rows (5, on my 1920x1200 display) based on its computed icon size.

Answer (score 1):

I have found no way to do that, nor have I heard of a way.  MacOSXHints is the place to watch for this kind of thing.

I have created folders in effect by dropping similar apps onto each other.  All QuickTime apps are together.  All Maintenance Apps are together, as are media viewing apps, etc.  I also move the least used apps to page 2

This reduces the number of pages for Launchpad and makes apps more accessible for me.  My most-used apps are still in my Dock so LP is rarely invoked.

This doesn't give you the solution you wanted, but may help as workaround.